# Parent and relevant child as loop maner

Tags: plsql

i have data as below

```
 A       B
1001    601
1002   1001
1003   1002
1004   1002
1005   1002
```

I need output as

```
1001
1002
1003
1001
1002
1004
1001
1002
1005
```

please help me

Comment: How do you know that you need this output? What are the rules for converting your input into output?

Comment: using connect by prior we can get 20% output , SELECT A FROM T108 T8 start with C = 1 connect by prior  A = B.  from this query i am getting 1001 1002 1003 but the rest seems wrong

Comment: What is the ALGORITHM? How do you know that your output sequence is right? Where is 601 in your output, for example?

Comment: retrive only parent child data.. dont bother irrelevant values

Comment: You still didn't answer the question! Besides what is parent?  What is child?

Comment: If we consider left outer join also we will get 80% output. But still what is the algorithm for this output. Plz Clarify

Comment: yes .. i've tried but gives the same output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
WITH sample_data AS(
    SELECT '1001' A, '601' B  FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1002' A, '1001' B  FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1003' A, '1002' B  FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1004' A, '1002' B  FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1005' A, '1002' B  FROM dual 
)
SELECT  TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE) tree_path
FROM 
(
    SELECT  SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(A, ','),2) tree_path 
    FROM    sample_data
    WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
    start with A = '1001'
    CONNECT BY PRIOR A =  B
), XMLTABLE(('"' || REPLACE(tree_path, ',', '","') || '"'))
```